# VirtualBox to HDD Partition

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, boot-partition

I have created a virtual machine in Virtual Box which boots up Windows XP. Is there any way to transfer this system to a HDD partition (NTFS)?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question? Should i reframe it?

Comment: You're looking to [V2P migration](http://techokarma.blogspot.com/2008/10/v2p-virtual-to-physical-for-virtualbox.html) a virtualbox machine to a physical partition? Check out that link and see if it helps you get started, I have no experience in this, but from what I've read it _could_ be tricky. Hopefully someone with experience will chime in.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I would upvote your comment if I could.

Comment: For one thing, because you are essentially putting a drive with Windows installed on it into a whole different system, the guest OS would need to re-detect and re-install pretty much **all** of its drivers for the physical system. This may or may not work; some people report that putting a hard-drive with Windows installed on it into a different system does work with some tweaking while others report that it fails catastrophically. You may want to keep your virtual drive file around for a while until you get it working.